# Why does Resharper recommend adding "StringComparison.Ordinal" to String.IndexOf?

Tags: vb.net, resharper, string-comparison, indexof

Under the "Common Practices and Code Improvements" rubric, Resharper says about this line:

```
If dt(0)("ThemeWidth").ToString.IndexOf("%") > "0" Then
    headerPanel.Width = Unit.Percentage(dt(0)("ThemeWidth").ToString.Replace("%", ""))
```

"*String.IndexOf(string) is culture-specific*" and encourages me to change it to this:

```
If dt(0)("ThemeWidth").ToString.IndexOf("%", StringComparison.Ordinal) > "0" Then
    headerPanel.Width = Unit.Percentage(dt(0)("ThemeWidth").ToString.Replace("%", ""))
```

Why? What does adding "*StringComparison.Ordinal*" do for me that improves this code?

Comment: The robot is likely just parroting stuff back from MSDN such as `Use StringComparison.Ordinal or StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase for comparisons as your safe default for culture-agnostic string matching.`  See [Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121(v=vs.110).aspx)... or dont take orders from robots

Comment: Was it Mark Twain who once said *Those who cannot remember the past are condemned to repeat it.*? See [Could string comparisons really differ based on culture when the string is guaranteed not to change](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10941375/1070452)

Comment: No, that was Santayana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```
Dim longText As String = "01234ss789ß"
Dim shortText As String = "ß"

Dim index1 As Integer = longText.IndexOf(shortText)
Dim index2 As Integer = longText.IndexOf(shortText, StringComparison.Ordinal)
```

Naively, you would expect `IndexOf` to return 10, because the "ß" sign only occurs at the very end of the string.

But in some cultures, the ß sign is seen as an alias for two ss and so the IndexOf without additional parameter will return 5 on some computers and 10 on other computers.

When using the parameter StringComparison.Ordinal, all cultural differences will be ignored and it will return 10 predictably on all computers.